# Foreign key with JSP and MySQL

Tags: mysql, jsp, foreign-keys

I have two tables.

I want to add a `course`.

In course table, there are columns

- course_id
- user_id
- course_code
- course_name

`user_id` is a **foreign key** referencing `login` table.

I want to add a course in database.

How can I get `user_id` in `login` table?

I have added `course_code` and `course_name`.

I use JSP, MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Once the user login , store the `user_id` in the session scope.

```
session.setAttribute("userid",user_id);
```

while you are adding a new course , get the value of `userid` from the `session` and insert it to the database. As it is unique for the session . you get the courses added for the unique id's

```
String usrId=(String) session.getAttribute("userid");
```

Hope this helps !!